# Exchange 2013 Edge server setup

Tags: exchange-2013, exchange

I am trying to upgrade my Exchange 2007 setup with Mailbox/CAB/Hub server, (and edge server), to a fully Exchange 2013 setup.

I have Exchange 2013 Mailbox server setup, running and working, (on win2012R2 VM in my AD domain), and I have successfully migrated some of the mailboxes to the new 2013 mail server.
I have also successfully installed Exchange 2013 in Edge Transport role, on another win2012R2 VM.  Unfortunately, the win2012R2 OS on that VM was also setup to be in the AD domain, which after reading the docs, I realize was a mistake. To fix that I removed the OS from the AD domain and made it just a stand-alone server in a workgroup.

Now I am trying to set up the Edge subscription, by running, in the Exchange Command Shell, on the Edge Server:

***New-EdgeSubscrition -FileName "C:\EdgesubscriptionInfp.xml"***

... but I am getting an error:

"*you can't use the FileName Parameter when running this command inside your Exchange organization*"

Now that I have changed the OS from being in the AD domain to just being a stand-alone server, do I need to uninstall exchange from the edge server, and completely re-install it for this to work ?

.******************************** More to this .********************************
In addition to the procedure that @theCleaner recommends below, when you take the machine out of the domain again, in the machine/Domain Change screen, you must hit the "More" button, and append the domain name to the machine name, so that it hasa fully qualified name (FQN) even though its not in the AD domain anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this before on older versions of Exchange when someone forgets that the Edge server shouldn't be on the domain.  We would have to uninstall Exchange from the edge server, reboot, and reinstall.  So yeah, I think that's the proper path to take here.  You might end up getting an error uninstalling now that the server is off the domain.  If you do, add it back to the domain and then uninstall Exchange.  Then remove it from the domain, reboot, and reinstall Exchange and the Edge role.

Comment: ahhhhhh, well, that's what I was afraid of.  It's a VM. Which route would you take, start with a brand new VM and do it right from scratch, or put this one back in the domain, uninstall Exchange, remove from domain, reinstall exchange ?

Comment: I would get Exchange uninstalled and then you can start with a new VM if you wish.  But just removing the VM might end up causing you issues if your existing Exchange org thinks that server is "still around" somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Edge Transport server requires data that resides in Active Directorythe Microsoft Exchange EdgeSync service (EdgeSync) handles this.

Is Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS) instance installed on the Edge Transport server. From what I recall this needs to be here.

To deploy an Edge Transport server and subscribe it to an Active Directory site, follow these steps: also found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997438(v=exchg.150).aspx

Install the Edge Transport server role.

Verify that the Mailbox servers and the Edge Transport server can locate one another using DNS name resolution.

On the Mailbox Server, configure the objects and settings to be replicated to the Edge Transport server.

On the Edge Transport server, create and export an Edge Subscription file.

Copy the Edge Subscription file to a Mailbox server or a file share that's accessible from the Active Directory site containing your Mailbox servers.

Import the Edge Subscription file to the Active Directory site.

Comment: In that link, step 3 reads "3.On the Mailbox Server, configure the objects and settings to be replicated to the Edge Transport server."
What does this mean ?  What objects?  Does the New-EdgeSubscription cmdlet take care of this for you?

Comment: And, yes, AD LDS is installed... I think installing Exchange and selecting the Edge Transport role did that for me ...